# Font colors set in a textarea created by wp_editor does not stay across updates (but stays correct in database)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

I created some meta boxes that use `wp_editor` to create rich-text fields (which are retrieved via WordPress' `get_metadata()`. When I use the TinyMCE buttons to make a word a specific color, it saves it and shows on the website as that color. **but** when I go to the page editor again, it shows in the TinyMCE box as black *and* if I click to update, it now makes the text show black on the website. Why is it not saving the color information?

```
wp_editor( 
    $savedValue, 
    "myTextBox", 
    array( 
        "wpautop" => false, 
        "media_buttons" => false, 
        "textarea_rows" => 5, 
        "quicktags" => true, 
        "tinymce" => array( "height" => 250 )
    )
);
```

When the form is submitted, in Javascript if I check the value it shows that word with the tags:

```
<span style="color: #00ffcc">word</span>
```

But after it's been updated and reloaded back into the TinyMCE box, it's now just:

```
<span>word</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Wordpress code was removing quotation marks.